# How to get current websocket queue size in Jetty?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

Time to time I getting write errors like

```
Error: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING
```

Looks like to avoid such problem I need control what is actually pushing into socket by myself. My current implementation simply push all data received and(looks like) because of slow clients queue become overfilled.

So question is how to get how much messages currently available in write buffer?
And from where I can get this magic number 10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That specific error ...

```
Error: Blocking message pending 10000 for BLOCKING
```

.. [only happens if you have 2 threads attempting to use blocking send over the same connection](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.2.3.v20140905/jetty-websocket/websocket-common/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/common/WebSocketRemoteEndpoint.java#L130).

*Note: the `10000` in that message is a blocking behavior/state mask value, not a count of messages, or a message ID.*

Basically, what is happening, is that there is an active blocking send of a message when another blocking send is attempted.  This commonly happens when using multiple threads.

Comment: Yes, I have part of code which trying to send data from different threads. Looks like this is not very correct approach:) Will it help if blocking calls will be replaced with future or writeCallbacks?